# Show/Hide collapsing rows in iView UI Table

Tags: vue.js, iview

I want to design a table in iView UI in which based upon my condition, it will populate data. These rows will have collapsing icon which will hide/show some rows based on my condition.
Here is the image showing concept:
[image]

How can I achieve (strictly) using [iView table](https://www.iviewui.com/components/table-en)?

Answer (score 0):

"iview" provides :row-class-name="rowClassName" props functionality for row manipulation.

You can use that property with className to show/hide your fields.

like,

```
<i-table :row-class-name="rowClassName" :columns="columns1" :data="data1"></i-table>
```

```
methods: {
        rowClassName (row, index) {
          return row.className
        }
    }
```

here is attached link for detail view
http://jsfiddle.net/nikita747/cn47qLj6/

Hope you satisfied with this

Comment: Wow!, that's what I exactly wanted. You are a Lifesaver! Perfect! Thanks a lot!